# Holomorphic function on a deleted ball missing a ball

Tags: complex-analysis

An exercise in my Complex Analysis textbook says, suppose $f:B'(0,1)\to \mathbb{C}$, where $B'(0,1) = B(0,1)\setminus 0$, is a holomorphic function such that there exists some open ball $B(b,\delta)$ such that $f$ does not take any value in it. I have to show that $f$ is a removable singularity.

Now, since $0$ is an isolated singularity it can be either removable, a pole or an essential singularity.
The case of essential can be ruled out because it's image misses an open ball so is not dense in $\mathbb{C}$.

It feels like $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{z}$ is a counterexample to the fact that $0$ cannot be a pole.

Is this correct or am I missing something ?

Comment: What happens to $\frac 1 {f(z)-b}$ as $z$ approaches $0$?

Comment: What is the meaning of $B'(0,1)$?

Comment: It is the open ball $B(0,1)$ with center $0$ deleted.

Comment: Your counterexample is correct, and the statement of the exercise is wrong, unless the book uses some unusual definition of removable singularity.